# TO_TIMESTAMP em Packages Oracle

Tags: oracle, backup, timestamp, packages

Estava fazendo algumas manutenções em objeto de banco de dados do oracle 11g, mas no meio dessa aventura acabei compilando e recompilando versões que deram erro.
Gostaria de saber se existe algum meio de realizar um TIMESTAMP em objetos de banco de dados PACKAGES no Oracle 11G.
Ex:
 Eu quero retornar o script contido no PACKAGE BODY A do dia 10/08/2018.
 Tentei essa solução mas aparentemente só com o usuário system é possível:

```
select    text 
from      dba_source as of timestamp 
          TO_TIMESTAMP('10/08/2018 14:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
where     name='PACKAGE_Q_DEU_MERDA' 
order by  line;
```

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, você quer recuperar a package como estava em 10/08/2018? Tipo restaurar um backup?

Comment: Se for isso, o oracle teria que estar com `flashback = enabled`, para ver o estado da package em uma determinada data, acessando com Sys, etc etc.

Comment: Isso David, eu tinha que fazer umas alterações nela e acabei fazendo alguma coisa errada e agora preciso voltar ela ao estado de antes de eu ter mexido, preciso voltar o script dela do dia 10/08/2018 14:00 por exemplo, editei com uma forma que achei na web mas deu um erro de acesso, como é no banco de dados da empresa o usuário system é meio restrito portanto gostaria de fazer com o usuário atual, não sei se existe alguma tabela de auditoria que armazena as alterações feitas em packages para que eu possa voltar uma delas.

Comment: Pesquisa sobre . Mas eu acho que boa tem como... Pesquise os termos.. segunda posso ver mais... Não vou ter acesso a nenhum Oracle fds